# Partitioning string in clojure in specific ways

Tags: clojure, partition

I'm working on a code that takes a bowling score (in terms of the 10 frames), and evaluates it. An example of a string would be `XXXXX6/XX7/XX5` where the score would be 248 or `62--43---2----X--` where the score would be 27.

My first idea was to try to split the string so that, it would group each frame together, and a strike separately as such; `62--43---2----X--` --> `((6 2) (--) (4 3) (--) (2 -)... (X) (--))`

From there, it would be easier to evaluate the scores. But I can't find a way to do that using partition or partition-by. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes I'm working in clojure like i mentioned in the prompt!

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably looking for is `re-seq`, which will split a string into a seq of strings that match a regex. In your case try `(re-seq #"X|\d\d|\d/|--|-\d|\d-" frames-str)` which will match one of:

- "X"
- A pair of digits
- A digit followed by a slash
- "--"
- A "-" and a number (in either order)

For your examples:

```
"XXXXX6/XX7/XX5"    -> ("X" "X" "X" "X" "X" "6/" "X" "X" "7/" "X" "X")
"62--43---2----X--" -> ("62" "--" "43" "--" "-2" "--" "--" "X" "--")
```

Comment: your regex is an overkill.  `#"X|[\d\-][\d\-/]"` would be enough.

Comment: That was the regex I started with actually, but I figured breaking it out into parts would be clearer in case the asker or another reader wasn't familiar with regex

Answer (score 1):

How about an excuse to write a bowling score grammar/parser using [instaparse](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse):

```
(def bowl-score-parser
  (insta/parser
    "S = F F F F F F F F F 10TH
     F = OPEN | CLOSED
     OPEN = ROLL ROLL
     CLOSED = STRIKE | SPARE
     10TH = OPEN |
            SPARE (STRIKE | ROLL) |
            STRIKE (SPARE | ROLL ROLL) |
            STRIKE STRIKE (STRIKE | ROLL)
     STRIKE = 'X'
     SPARE = ROLL '/'
     ROLL = PINS | MISS
     PINS = #'[1-9]'
     MISS = '-'"))
```

This parses ten *frames* of a bowling score, with special rules for the tenth frame.

1. Each of the first nine frames is either `OPEN` (pins left standing) or `CLOSED` (all pins down).
2. `OPEN` is two `ROLL`s, which are either a number of pins down or a miss. `CLOSED` is either a `STRIKE` or `SPARE`.
3. `10TH` describes the possible states for the tenth frame, which is surprisingly confusing! I could've gotten something wrong here.

Here's the parser output for your test case:

```
(bowling-score-parser "XXXXX6/XX7/XX5")
=>
[:S
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:SPARE [:ROLL [:PINS "6"]] "/"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:STRIKE "X"]]]
 [:F [:CLOSED [:SPARE [:ROLL [:PINS "7"]] "/"]]]
 [:10TH [:STRIKE "X"] [:STRIKE "X"] [:ROLL [:PINS "5"]]]]
```

Note: this parser permits an invalid number of total pins in a frame, but you could make a more specific grammar/parser or handle that case post-parsing.